# Why does Eclipse put "/faces/" in my URL?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, maven, weblogic11g

I created a Java Dynamic Web Project and converted it to maven. I then added a JSP page in the WebContent folder called home.jsp. I perform on home.jsp:

Right click --> Run As --> Run on server

The web page displays an error.

The URL is : /futurevoicedetails/faces/home.jsp

When i remove the /faces : /futurevoicedetails/home.jsp

The page displays.
My question is where has the **/faces** came from. I have not added any code to this program which makes me assume it is a server or eclipse error. I am running the web app on web logic server 11g and am using Eclipse Luna. 
Has anyone had this problem before and if so, what is the solution?

EDIT: After a few more runs of eclipse, it crashed. The server sometimes causes eclipse to crash, and i have to restart my computer to get back onto eclipse. Now it is throwing all sorts of errors just loading up eclipse. I doubt this has anything to do with the before problem. I have resorted to downloading eclipse again.

Comment: Check for your `web.xml` , may be context param tag has that

Comment: Try to right click on a project not on some page.

Comment: The web.xml is fine san, and the project throws the same error. It is very strange because i have never seen this before and have literally no clue where it is coming from